# Is C(R) compact space in regard to given metric

Tags: analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $C(\mathbb{R})$ be a set of continous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $d:C(\mathbb{R})\times C(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$d(f,g)=\begin{cases} 0 , & f=g ;\\
\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}} (\arctan{ |f(x)|} + \arctan{ |g(x)|}) , & f\ne g .
\end{cases}$$
I proved that this is indeed a complete metric space by checking that every Cauchy sequence converges, but I would like to know if it is compact metric space, because then I could directly deduce completeness?
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this is what the metric is supposed to be? It appears $d(f_n,f)$ can tend to $0$ only if $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes, this is the metric. Am I wrong, the space is not complete?

Comment: $f_n=n$ gives a sequence with no convergent subsequence.